Rotational averages of tensors
I was recently thinking about taking a rotational average of a tensor - i.e., take all the possible rotations of the tensor and average them. A physical example of this could be getting isotropic property values in the gas/liquid state, where anisotropy is averaged out by random rotation.
For example, for a 3D rank-2 tensor $\mathbf{T}$, the "isotropic average" is just $\frac 1 3 \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{T})\delta_{ij}$.
Part of this is easy to see intuitively, since $\delta_{ij}$ is the only isotropic tensor in 3D. However, I don't see whether one could easily get the prefactor $\frac 1 3 \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{T})$.
This is even more pressing in 2D, where we have two isotropic rank-2 tensors - $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ij}$. The rotational average will be a weighed sum of these two - but which one?
We can do a bit of algebra here. If $\mathbf{T} = \begin{pmatrix} T_{xx} & T_{xy} \\ T_{yx} & T_{yy} \end{pmatrix}$, we can easily multiply out $\mathbf{R}(\theta)\mathbf{T}\mathbf{R}(-\theta)$ and integrate the result ($\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$) to obtain the average
$\langle T\rangle_{ij}=\frac 1 2 (T_{xx} + T_{yy})\delta_{ij} + \frac 1 2(T_{xy} - T_{yx}) \epsilon_{ij}$.
Question 1. Writing this all out explicitly and then integrating is a bit painful, especially for more dimensions or higher rank. Is there a nicer way to do this? (Maybe something with spherical tensors?)
Question 2. How does this generalise to more dimensions and higher rank tensors? E.g., in the rank-3 case, there is also only one isotropic tensor, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ (I'm not sure whether this is also true in 2D). But what will be the prefactor? And what about higher ranks, where there are multiple independent isotropic tensors?

In the 2D case, the two tensors are linearly independent (one is symmetric, one is antisymmetric).
In 3 dimensions the isotropic tensors for rank $N=0,1,2,3$ are $1, {\rm N/A}, \delta_{ij}, \epsilon_{ijk}$, respectively.
From there, it gets complicated. The number of fundamental isotropic Cartesian tensors (FICT) are:
For even $n$:
$$N(n) = \frac{n!}{\big(\frac n 2\big)!2^{n/2}}$$
For odd $n$
$$N(n) = \frac{n!}{3!\big(\frac{n-3} 2\big)!2^{(n-3)/2}}$$
while the total number of isotropic tensors is:
$$M(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n+1}2]}
\Big[
\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 2k\end{array}\right)-
\frac 1 2
\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ 2k-1\end{array}\right)
\Big]
\left(\begin{array}{c} 2k \\ k\end{array}\right)
$$
but they are not all independent, and are related by Capelli's identites:
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta_{ip} & \delta_{iq} & \delta_{ir} \\
\delta_{jp} & \delta_{jq} & \delta_{jr} \\
\delta_{kp} & \delta_{kq} & \delta_{kr} \\
\end{array}
\right|
=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{pqr}
$$
$$\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
\delta_{ip} & \delta_{iq} & \delta_{ir} & \delta_{is} \\
\delta_{jp} & \delta_{jq} & \delta_{jr} & \delta_{js}\\
\delta_{kp} & \delta_{kq} & \delta_{kr} & \delta_{ks}\\
\delta_{mp} & \delta_{mq} & \delta_{mr} & \delta_{ms}\\
\end{array}
\right|
= 0
$$
(I mean duh?, right?)
So at rank 4 you have:
$$ \delta_{ij}\delta_{km} $$
$$ \delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} $$
$$ \delta_{im}\delta_{jk} $$
NIST, yes they do tensors, too, has computed them to rank-8:
https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/79b/jresv79bn1-2p49_a1b.pdf
Oh, and the $\frac 1 3$ just normalizes $\delta_{ii}$, that is, for an isotropic tensor...lets use pressure $p$, which is tensor form goes like the diagonal part of the stress tensor:
$$ \sigma_{ij} =N p\delta_{ij} $$
So:
$$ Tr(\sigma) = Np(\delta_{xx} + \delta_{yy} 
+\delta_{zz} = Np(1+1+1) = 3Np = p $$
so $N=\frac 1 3$.
